# Weird action in HStack in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a List where each row shows two buttons with HStack.

when I tap any one button, both actions will triggered instead of just one.
My code is as follow:

```
struct NineView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<5) { item in
                getContent()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func getContent() -> some View {
        DoubleView {
            print("h1")
        } action2: {
            print("h2")
        }
    }
}

struct DoubleView: View {
    
    var action1: () -> Void
    var action2: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {

            Button {
                action1()
            } label: {
                Text("B1")
                
            }
            
            Button {
                action2()
            } label: {
                Text("B2")
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Why List is behaving so weird?
is there any issue in the code?

Thank you for your time!

Answer: setting buttonStyle will work! very weird issue